# Pandas Excel writer update existing excel file

Tags: python, pandas, excel

How do I update an excel file and not overwrite it?

```
#Run function

query_data(atlantic_stones)
query_data(aircool_north)
query_data(aircool_south)

#Create some Pandas dataframes

dfastones = query_data(atlantic_stones)
dfanorth = query_data(aircool_north)
dfasouth = query_data(aircool_south)

#Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('data_repository.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

dfastones.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='atlantic_stones')
dfanorth.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='aircool_north')
dfasouth.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='aircool_south')

#Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.

writer.save()
```

Comment: Try one of the suggested answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20219254/how-to-write-to-an-existing-excel-file-without-overwriting-data-using-pandas Your problem seems very similar